# How to sort item names in QT treeview alphabetically ignorent of the case?

Tags: qt, sorting, qtreeview

Below is my treeview code, and I want sort to sort the directory keys alphabetically whatever whether they start with a capital letter or not, for example, the "auto-update" should be listed right after the "Audio", how to implement this? Thanks.

I heared that you can override the virtual QAbstractItemModel::sort() to implement your own case-insensitive sorting. Can any one can provide the code example?

```
RegistryTreeView::RegistryTreeView(Registry &inRegistry, QWidget *inParent)
{
    mModel = new RegistryItemModel;
    mModel->setRegistry(&inRegistry);

    mTreeView = new QTreeView;
    mTreeView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::DefaultContextMenu);
    mTreeView->setModel(mModel);
    mTreeView->setItemDelegate(new RegistryItemDelegate(mModel));
    mTreeView->installEventFilter(new A utoSelectEventFilter(this));
    
    mainLayout->addWidget(mTreeView);
    
}

class RegistryItemModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
Q_OBJECT;

public:
RegistryItemModel(QWidget *parent=NULL);
virtual ~RegistryItemModel();
......
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you really think you get another answer than the on here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/143917 - it was properly answered...

Comment: @chehrlic , I'm the guy posted that question, unfortunately, nobody can provide a example on how to override the virtual QAbstractItemModel::sort() to implement your own case-insensitive sorting.

Comment: `how to override the virtual QAbstractItemModel::sort()` - I don't understand what the problem is here - do you don't know how to override a function or how to do case-insensitive comparaision of two QStrings?